# Is my electric impact drill useless?

Tags: drill, masonry, drill-bit

** I am not seeking a product review, but right/wrong choice for my drill machine**

Hello,

I have a Terratek 500w impact drill (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00H3KYLQY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I am having real hard time drilling through my walls after 12mm. I can drill through plaster bits, but not with masonary bits at all. When I see youtube or DIY videos, it seems everyone is managing to drill through stones/bricks/masonary bits way quicker than I can. I am literally standing and holding the drill machine for 5 mins and dead stuck after having a hole for 12 mm. This is what I have done:

1. Tried switching between rotary and hammer mode - nothing
2. Tried upping the rev - didn't work
3. Tried with thinner bits (4mm) and then thicker bits (6mm) - nothing
4. Used masonry bits (end) of the drill head - nothing

[image]

The marked areas are where I am trying to drill. So it's upside down and will be used for fitting vertical blinds. The screws are for brackets which will latch onto the blind frame.

I am getting joint/deltoid pains after holding the drill for 5 mins and not getting through, it'd be appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction.

Regards,

Comment: Are these quality masonary bits or a cheap “chinesium” brand?

Comment: 1 - When it is in hammer mode, is it actually *hammering*? 2 - Can you find some scrap brick or concrete block and practice on it in the open?

Comment: Do you know what's behind the plaster? A masonry bit won't drill into steel - can you see in the hole? You can get a reasonable set of drill bits in a green box for about £15.99 from B&Q or Amazon.

Comment: Can you check for metal obstructions at the bottom of the hole with a magnet? And you should be aware that the youtube videos probably feature a "Bulldog" style rotary hammer drill, which is a different beast from yours.

Comment: I have to agree with @andrew Morton steel is used inside masonry walls for reenforcement and the carbide tip is made for fracturing the aggregate not cutting steel. If you look at the tip and the carbide is still in place you are probably hitting steel. If your bit has no carbide left just high speed steel worn off from burning in one place it may be a chinesium brand as solar Mike mentions.

Comment: Hi all - yes I totally forgot that having the steel beams are a possibility. And I actually have drill bits for metal head. Shall I try that when I get stuck? Also, the drill holes are upside down :( - how do I check if there is a steel reinforcement beam there?

Comment: @ha9u63ar Use some (mineral) oil on the drill bit if you can for cutting metal, and start with a small bit and work you way up the sizes. If you can't see in, you could try poking a thin screwdriver in and tapping and scraping at it to see if that gives any clues as toi the material. What are you intending to install?

Comment: Given the picture, there's every possibility you have a steel lintel over that window. Is there anyone nearby that might have some insight into how your building is built?

Comment: @ha9u63ar It looks like you need to search for "putting up blinds steel lintel".

Answer (score 6):

### If you're not drilling, *stop* drilling

Anytime your drill isn't actually moving forward progress, ***immediately*** stop and troubleshoot why not.

**Doing anything else is just destroying equipment for no good reason*.

Drilling works like any other material-working operation: either it's having the desired effects, or it's having undesired effects.

You need to figure out more stuff about what is going on.  We can help, but we need to know what you're drilling into, and what bits you are using to do the drilling.   It would be nice to find out if you're hitting something metallic.

Metal in concrete *can* be drilled through... it just *shouldn't be*.  For a variety of reasons including structural strength, corrosion, a structural plate, or a plate designed to prevent you from drilling into wires or plumbing, plumbing, metal electrical conduit or rebar.

The fact that you're not telling us this suggests to me that you're rather new to such work and not well-versed in the vocabulary yourself.  As such, doing some more self-education might be called for.

Comment: Okay fair enough, I have added an image of the window opening including the marks where I am trying to drill holes for screw

Comment: If the OP is drilling into a block/brick wall, it's entirely possible that there's a steel lintel across that window opening that's holding up the block above. That's probably more likely than hitting protection plates at that point when drilling up into the top of the window frame. In any case, stopping to reassess the situation is 100% the right thing to do.